# PyCharm can't find virtualenv interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I have a Python project set up in a virtualenv that I created directly from the terminal. When I try to open it in PyCharm, I am able to see the files, but I can't change the project interpreter to use my virtualenv. I am able to see the python executable file both through the WSL terminal and the Windows File Explorer, but when I try to add it as a project interpreter from PyCharm, I am unable to find it.

I have tried deleting my `.idea` directory and adding the project to PyCharm again. I have tried creating a new project in PyCharm using my project's root directory. I have tried editing the `SDK_HOME` variable in `.idea/workspace.xml` to be the location of the python executable, but it didn't change the project interpreter.

Anyone have any ideas?

I am using WSL for the terminal and Windows 10 for my OS.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't show up in that drop-down list.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v1bLNItxBM

Comment: I have tried adding a project interpreter the normal way already, but it doesn't work. The "ok" button is grayed out.

Comment: What is the virtual env path

Comment: Can you provide the python.exe in virtual env in pychar

Comment: The python executable is located at C:\Users\[username]\GitHub\[project name]\venv\bin\python

Comment: Did you choose the existing environment option

Comment: In pycharm instead of new environment

Comment: I have tried every option - neither works.

Comment: When I do new environment, it complains that the environment location directory is not empty - because it isn't. When I do existing environment, I simply cannot find the executable in the explorer.

Comment: Once create a new directory and try whether its working or not

Comment: Create a new one

Comment: I ended up making a copy of the source code, requirements.txt file, and git files, and then deleting the directory and recreating the project/virtualenv through PyCharm. It works now :)

Comment: I still wonder what the issue was though.. maybe something to do with the fact that I originally created the virtualenv using WSL.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because what you have is a symlink and not a copy of the interpreter.
Try creating the environment by adding the `--copies` option:

`virtualenv myenv --copies`

Comment: If you see in the comments, it appears I was able to get it to work somehow, but thanks for the answer regardless!